# Display posts from a category

Tags: categories, wp-query

I am trying to display a bunch of posts from a single category on the category page, using multiple loops.

```
<div id="featured-content" class="clearfix">

<?
// assign the variable as current category
$categoryvariable = $cat;
echo($cat);
?>


<?php query_posts('$cat'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&offset=0&category=$cat'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "1") { break; } else { ?>


        <article class="d-all d-pad">
            <ul class="meta">
                <li class="date"><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li>
                <li class="region"><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'regions' ,  ' ' ); ?></li>
                <li class="cat"><?php the_category(', ') ?></li>
            </ul>
            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) :?>
                <figure class="img clearfix">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-image', array( 'class' => 'featured-image' ) ); ?>
                </figure>
            <?php else :?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
        </article>

<?php $count1++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong as its not displaying the articles for the category page I am on.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing `query_posts` and then immediately `get_posts`. This looks wrong. Remove the `query_posts` call.

Also, where does your `$cat` come from? It doesn't appear to be set anywhere in your code snippet. Try to start with setting it first:

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
```

Comment: Basing it on this page, http://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/  point 4.  I have multiple loops on the page.

Also the $cat is being set.

<?
    // assign the variable as current category
$categoryvariable = $cat;
echo($cat);
?>

That display a number, which is the category id, so I know it works.

Comment: [Read this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) for a discussion on why using query_posts is a bad idea. Author of tutorial himself [agrees](http://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/#comment-3765). As for `$cat`, in PHP assignment operator works from right to left. The variable is most likely being set somewhere higher up, that's why it's defined. Whole line `$categoryvariable = $cat;` is therefore useless.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand.